# FFmpeg filtergraph for concatenate and amix doesn't work. Out of memory error

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate two mp3 files, one after few seconds from the other with FFmpeg in an android application. I'm using [this library](https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java)

To achieve this I'm creating an audio silence with **aevalsrc** and concatenate to this one the second input. After, with **amix**, I'm merging the result with the first input. This is the command:

```
String[] cmd = {"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/input1.mp3", "-i", "/storage/emulated/0/input2.mp3", "-filter_complex", "aevalsrc=0:d=8[s1]; [s1][1:a]concat=n=2:a=1:v=0[a2]; [0:a][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest", "-c:a", "libmp3lame",  "/storage/emulated/0/finito.mp3"};
```

The output mp3 is created but it only contains the first input, like if it was just making a copy. The FFMpeg version is 3.0.1. The output shown is:

```
 I/ffmpeg(27265): [mp3 @ 0xb5bdf000] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 4513.
 I/ffmpeg(27265): Input #0, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/input1.mp3':
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Metadata:
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     track           : 0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     TYER            : 0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Duration: 00:00:01.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 148 kb/s
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
 I/ffmpeg(27265): [mp3 @ 0xb5bdf600] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 4513.
 I/ffmpeg(27265): Input #1, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/input2.mp3':
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Metadata:
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     track           : 0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     TYER            : 0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Duration: 00:00:00.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 226 kb/s
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
 I/ffmpeg(27265): Output #0, mp3, to '/storage/emulated/0/finito.mp3':
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Metadata:
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     TRCK            : 0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     TYER            : 0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     TSSE            : Lavf57.25.100
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
 I/ffmpeg(27265):     Metadata:
 I/ffmpeg(27265):       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libmp3lame
 I/ffmpeg(27265): Stream mapping:
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> amix:input0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> concat:in1:a0
 I/ffmpeg(27265):   amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
 I/ffmpeg(27265): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 I/ffmpeg(27265): size=      18kB time=00:00:01.09 bitrate= 133.0kbits/s speed=2.18x    
 I/ffmpeg(27265): Error while filtering: Out of memory
 I/ffmpeg(27265): size=      28kB time=00:00:01.75 bitrate= 131.1kbits/s speed=2.43x    
 I/ffmpeg(27265): video:0kB audio:28kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.999261%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error:

```
I/ffmpeg(27265): Error while filtering: Out of memory
```

Use adelay instead.

```
String[] cmd = {"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/input1.mp3", "-i", "/storage/emulated/0/input2.mp3", "-filter_complex", "[1]adelay=8000|8000[a2];[0:a][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest", "-c:a", "libmp3lame",  "/storage/emulated/0/finito.mp3"};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I've tried you alternative, but I got the same exact result and same error message Error while filtering: Out of memory

Comment: I did a try and I execute only the adelay part and it's woprking ok (creating an 8 seconds audio with my second input at the end). It looks the issue is when it tries to amix the result with the first input.

Comment: Both your and my command works ok at my end. Try with a newer build of ffmpeg.